# Migrating text formatting from a cell to another cell that references it

Tags: google-apps-script

In one of the sheets of a google spreadsheet there is a cell which I am referencing in another cell. The text gets copied fine but without any of the formatting. So if I have any bold or italic writing it will show as normal writing in the referenced cell.

I have tried the below script but it's not working as it should. Instead of copying the whole formatting it copies just the cell borders and it copies it to multiple cells below as well(to a total of 7 cell, the target one plus 6 below).

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var activeSheetName = activeSheet.getName();
  var activeCell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
  if ( activeSheet.getName().indexOf("Job ID") != -1 && activeCell.getRow() == 4 && activeCell.getColumn() == 15 ) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Active Jobs');
    var jobRowNumber = findJobIdRow();
    var sourceCell = activeSheet.getRange(4,1,15,1);
    sourceCell.copyFormatToRange(targetSheet, 16, 16, jobRowNumber, jobRowNumber);
  }
}

function findJobIdRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var jobID = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,1).getValue();
  var column = ss.getSheetByName('Active Jobs').getRange(2,1,ss.getSheetByName('Active Jobs').getMaxRows()-2,1);
  var values = column.getValues(); // get all data in one call
  for(var ct = 0; ct < values.length-1; ct++){
    if(values[ct][0] == jobID){
      var ct = ct+2;
      break;
    }
  }
  return ct;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your invocation of [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) may contain an error: 
you write

```
var sourceCell = activeSheet.getRange(4,1,15,1);
```

but this range is not a single cell, it's a 15-by-1 range starting from A4. The order is (row, column, numRows, numColumns). Perhaps you meant

```
var sourceCell = activeSheet.getRange(4,15,1,1);
```

Second, I suggest using [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object)) method, which has options that supersede the functionality of "copy...ToRange" methods.

```
var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(...);
sourceCell.copyTo(targetRange, {formatOnly: true});
```